# Trying to add trailing slash with htaccess, results in a absolute path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'm trying to achive is to have all urls on my page look like `http://domain.com/page/`, no extensions, but a trailing slash. If a user happends to write `http://domain.com/page` or `http://domain.com/page.php` it will redirect to the first url. After some googling i found this code, and it's close to working, but when you leave out the trailing slash in your request the url becomes something like `http://domain.com/Users/"..."/page/` and therefor returns a 404.
My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

I've been trying to add an additional rule but I really don't get any of this and I haven't been able to find any answers.

Answer (score 2):

For a scenario like this one, the `.htaccess` author has to consider both what the browser URL bar should display and what file the web server should return/execute.  Note also that each external redirect starts the processing of the rewrite directives over.

With that in mind, start by taking care of which file is returned when the URL is in the correct format:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ([^./]+)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

Then, deal with URLs with no trailing slash by redirecting them with `[R=301]`:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.[^.]*$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Note that the first of these two rules should also take care of the case where there is a filename (like something.php) but also a trailing slash by eliminating the filename extension and re-adding the slash.

Keep in mind that, if your internal directory structure does not match what the web server is serving (as is often the case in shared hosting scenarios), you will likely need to add a `RewriteBase` directive immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive.  [See the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) for an explanation.

Comment: Well put, that helped me out too!

Comment: Thank you for your help, Andrew! It looks very neat and I follow logic, but this actually just makes it access the correct file when using a file extension or a trailing slash. It doesn't remove any extensions and doesn't add that trailing slash either, actually returns a 404 when not using a trailing slash..

Comment: @Fredrik Are you wanting to remove *any* extension in the URL?  If so, are you then looking to add .php internally?  For example, would you want http://www.example.com/something.html to redirect the browser to http://www.example.com/something/, which then uses something.php internally to serve the request?

Comment: I want to always redirect the browser to example.com/something/, so that it doesn't matter if the user writes in example.com/something.php or example.com/something, he'll end up att example.com/something/ anyway. Internally I want that url to refer to something.php. I realize that this was a bit more complicated than I first expected.
And I also fount out that the second segment of the code I posted, is the one doesn't seem to be working properly. If I comment it out, the server behaves exactly as before.

Comment: @Fredrik I made some small changes.  Let me know if you this still doesn't work as you expect, and if not, how.

Comment: It doesn't work this time either, unfortunately. It acts exactly as I mentioned two posts ago. It does disply the correct file if I write ".../example/" and ".../example.php" but it doesn't rewrite the url displayed in the browser and it does not work for ".../example".